# Tailwind hover effect not working with custom css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

I'm new in web dev. I try react with Tailwind for my first project. But i add free animated background from internet. The background consist of  normal css and html. This is the css file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700");

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
}

.context {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.context h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.area {
  background: #b3ffab;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(25deg, #b3ffab 0%, #12fff7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, #b3ffab 0%, #12fff7 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgb(17, 218, 94, 0.4);
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

In my jsx file i use:

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  const percentage = 80;
  return (
    <div className="area w-screen">
/* all other web components*/
      <div>
        <ul className="circles z-1 ">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      /*some footer*/

    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

[image]

Basically it just apply some animation dan effect to `<li>` components. I found that all  my hover effect don't work. And when i remove this :

```
   <div>
        <ul className="circles z-1 ">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

It works. Why is this happen? and how to solve this?

Comment: Can you add the html of the items that you are having hovering issues with? Also the relavent CSS of the hover (I don't see a single `hover` in your provided CSS)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the particle effect. That time, i don't know that it will block my click, so anything behind that can't be clicked

Answer (score -1):

Get started with Tailwind CSS

Tailwind CSS works by scanning all of your HTML files, JavaScript components, and any other templates for class names, generating the corresponding styles and then writing them to a static CSS file.

It's fast, flexible, and reliable — with zero-runtime.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation